# Что можно использовать для обмена bluetooth пакетами?

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

На python есть библиотека pybluez, но она не устанавливается на android'е. Какие еще есть библиотеки для взаимодействия с bluetooth`ом через termux/pydroid? (Или есть ли простые аналоги на других языках (джава, С#)?). Хотел написать блютуз чат с gui под андроид. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Kotlin и нативная разработка вам поможет: https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/Kotlin-BLE-Library или ее предшественник https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/Android-BLE-Library/

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja спасибо, попробую выучить. Хотелось бы аналог и на пк, чтобы отдельно не переписывать с нуля.

Comment: Мобильный и десктопные BLE стеки несовместимы (возможно iOS и macOS только), поэтому скорее всего придется писать дважды.